# Android View Rotation around an Anchor

Tags: android, animation

I have tried for a few days to recreate this animation

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/73/e4/1b/73e41b839128536ad2ffd84e4a543517.gif

Rotating the items, doesn't seem to work and even calculating the X and Y (Using: (X,Y) = (rCos, rSin) does not seem to do the trick either.

The closet I am able to get to this is by placing the Views in a container and then rotating. That gives the desired rotation but then all the items fall into place at once. Translating the views, while the container rotates does not provided correct results.

Is there a trick to this that I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I've almost figured it out. I now have the view following the correct arc, however I can not get it to rotate around a specific point. See logic for rotating view.

```
view.setPivotY(anchorView.getY() + anchorView.getHeight()/2);
view.setPivotX(anchorView.getX() + anchorView.getWidth()/2);
view.setRotation(fraction * -90);
```

Instead of pivoting around the coordinates it seems to pivot around a different point.

Comment: Post your code. [See code similar functionality](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that isn't quite what i'm looking for. Making the independent items rotate around the button is what I need to do. Just having them expand for the center, after everything i've tried, would be easy.